# How to find the node elements which is not inside the <a> tag using HtmlCleaner?

Tags: java, data-mining, htmlcleaner

I use HTMLCleaner for mining the data....
Here is how does it works:

```
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    final String siteUrl = "http://www.apple.com/";

    TagNode node = cleaner.clean(new URL(siteUrl));
    TagNode[] aTagNode = node.getAllElements(true);

    for(int i = 0; i< aTagNode.length; i++){
            if(!aTagNode[i].hasAttribute("a")){
                System.out.println(aTagNode[i].getText());
            }
    }
```

But I find there are some problems....
For example, get the text:

```
                <a href="/choose-your-country/"> 
                    <img src="http://images.apple.com/home/elements/worldwide_us.png" alt="United States of America" height="22" width="22" /> 
                    <span class="more">Choose your country or region</span> 
                </a>
```

The "Choose your country or region" is inside the span tag, but it's parent node is a "a" tag..... I don't want it also, I just want something like this....:

```
<p class="left">Shop the <a href="/store/">Apple Online Store</a> (1-800-MY-APPLE), visit an <a href="/retail/">Apple Retail Store</a>, or find a <a href="/buy/">reseller</a>.</p>
```

I want the result is `Stop the`, `(1-800-MY-APPLE),visit an`, `or find a`, and `.`
Because `Apple Online Store`, `Apple Retail Store` and `reseller` is the text inside the a tag, so, I want to ignore these words. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    TagNode[] aTagNode = node.getAllElements(true);
    ArrayList<TagNode> tagNodes = new ArrayList<TagNode>();
    Set<TagNode> toBeRemoved = new HashSet<TagNode>();
    for(int i = 0; i< aTagNode.length; i++){
            if(!aTagNode[i].hasAttribute("a")){
                tagNodes.add(aTagNode[i]);
            }else{
                TagNode[] children = aTagNode[i].getChildTags().
                for(TagNode child : children) {
                toBeRemoved.add(child);
                }
             }
    }
    for(TagNode node : tagNodes){
      if(!toBeRemoved.contains(node)){
        System.out.println(node.getText());
      }
    }
```